# Import one node from one document to another

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

My xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Employees>
<employee eId="123" empName="Name"/>
<employee eId="456" empName="Name"/>
<Employees>
```

I was trying copy the xml elements from one document to another. With a modification in `empName`

```
NodeList employees = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
Element emp = null;
for(int i=0; i<employees.getLength();i++){
  emp = (Element) employees.item(i);
  emp.setAttribute("empName", "Name"+i);            
}
```

And here is the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Employees>
<employee eId="123" empName="Name0"/>
<employee eId="456" empName="Name1"/>
<Employees>
```

But I have to include the old elements also in the new document.(Any order is fine). So it should be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Employees>
<employee eId="123" empName="Name"/>
<employee eId="456" empName="Name"/>
<employee eId="123" empName="Name0"/>
<employee eId="456" empName="Name1"/>
<Employees>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `adoptNode` method on `org.w3c.dom.Document` is used to move instances of `Node` from one `Document` to another.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#adoptNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29

Once the nodes have been "adopted" you can use the `appendChild` method on `org.w3c.dom.Node` to put them in the correct spot:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29